# FlutterFire does signs user out but does not navigate to signin screen

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using FlutterFire AuthUI in my Flutter app.
In the app root I use AuthGate widget that listens to the `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()` to decide to show the sign in page or the home page.

Everything works fine, but when I sign in from a screen other than the home page, the user is signed out but the screen does not switch to the sign in page again.
When I sign out from the home page it works as expected.

This is my AuthGate:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return SignInScreen(
            providerConfigs: [
              EmailProviderConfiguration(),
            ],
          );
        }
        return TimelineScreen();
      }),
    );
  }
```

This is how I use it in the app root:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider<AppUser>(
    create: (context) => AppUser(),
    child: MaterialApp(
      home: AuthGate(),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Signing out from a page other than the home page:

```dart
                SettingsTile(
                    title: "Sign out",
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.logout),
                    onPressed: (context) {
                      FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

signOut() is async method, adding await should do the trick

```
 SettingsTile(
         title: "Sign out",
         trailing: Icon(Icons.logout),
         onPressed: (context) async {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
       }),
```

Comment: It did not work. I still can see "Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event." in the console but nothing happens.
I can do: 
                      FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AuthGate()),
                            (route) => false);
                      });
But then I'm not benefiting from the steam at the root of the app.